# How to merge two arrays between start_time and end_time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, calendar

I have one array (15min):

```
One
09:00 09:15
09:15 09:30
09:30 09:45
09:45 10:00
10:00 10:15
10:15 10:30
10:30 10:45
10:45 11:00
...
```

And another with my calendar:

```
Two
09:00 10:00 - Calendar 1 (60min)
10:00 10:15 - Calendar 2 (15min)
11:00 11:30 - Calendar 3 (30min)
```

I need to combine like this:

```
Result
09:00 10:00 - Calendar 1
10:00 10:15 - Calendar 2
10:15 10:30
10:30 10:45
10:45 11:00
11:00 11:30 - Calendar 3
```

Thanks for help!

Im trying this:

```
foreach ($one as $d1) {
    echo $d1['time'];
        foreach ($two as $d2) {
            if ($d1['time'] == $d2['time']) {
            echo 'Ok';
        }
    }
}
```

And this:
$result = array_merge($one, $two); 
But its returning:

```
09:00 09:15
09:15 09:30
09:30 09:45
09:45 10:00
10:00 10:15
10:15 10:30
10:30 10:45
10:45 11:00
09:00 10:00 - Calendar 1 (60min)
10:00 10:15 - Calendar 2 (15min)
11:00 11:30 - Calendar 3 (30min)
```

Original Arrays

```
Array 1 (15min)
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:00
            [end_time] => 09:15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:15
            [end_time] => 09:30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:30
            [end_time] => 09:45
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:45
            [end_time] => 10:00
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 10:00
            [end_time] => 10:15
        )
)


Array 2 (my calendar)
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:00
            [end_time] => 09:30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:30
            [end_time] => 09:45
        )
)


Array 3 (Result)
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:00
            [end_time] => 09:30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:30
            [end_time] => 09:45
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 09:45
            [end_time] => 10:00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 10:00
            [end_time] => 10:15
        )
)
```

Example: Array 3 [0] merged!

Comment: How exactly do you want the output array? Post that one too. It would be clear.

Comment: There's no MySQL here

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, i have two tables (calendar and time) calendar with columms: datetime_start and datetime_end, time with columms: time_start, time_end and period. Columm period can be: 15 or 30 minutes (for range os minutes).

Comment: My point is that it's not relevant to the question.